# Quick insert of variables into SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that is used often enough to be a pain that I have not been able to come up with a solution to. I suppose this could be used for much more that what I need it for.  The query is simple enough.

```
SELECT
  *value*
FROM
  *TABLE*
WHERE
  'Incident Number' ="*B*"
OR 'Incident Number'="*X*"
OR 'Incident Number'="*Z*"
OR 'Incident Number'="*C*";
```

I have a list that contains all of the "Incident Number"'s but unable to find a quick way of getting them into the query to run other than copy and paste. Note that this query is entered into a third party program so I am unsure it's limitations when it comes to how complex the SQL it will handle.

Comment: If you could directly access the database, you could just upload your list into a temporary table, and use it for your query.

Comment: And how is this related to tag [tag:batch-file]??

Comment: Can you set it up as a STORED procedure that take a variable say, VARCHAR(8000) and you simply feed it a 'Val1,Val2,ValN' string that is parsed out?

Comment: I was not sure where to place question. I apologize, but Batch-file is something I am familiar with could be possibly used here.  I am sure there is possibly 10 solutions to this, but the light is not going on for me.

Comment: I can not set it up as a stored procedure as the query is entered into an ITSM software to query a ticketing system.

Comment: EDIT.  Should add ITSM is a 3rd part software that is not designed or at least my access to it only allows basic select, insert, update statements.  Can perform joins, but not in this scenario.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the list into excel? Write a simple ="OR 'Incident Number'="*"&A1&"*"" type formula and select and paste that?

Comment: Yes, the list comes from an excel spreadsheet.  Thank you very much, This worked like a champ. ="OR 'Incident Number'="&BXX&"" .